# Which Hive version can be installed on Hadoop 3.1.1

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I plan to install Hive on top of Hadoop 3.1.1 multinode cluster. Which Hive version is supported in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Any Hive 3+ version MUST :)) work. Per [Hadoop Compatibility policies](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Compatibility.html#Java_Binary_compatibility_for_end-user_applications_i.e._Apache_Hadoop_ABI), *"Minor Apache Hadoop revisions within the same major revision MUST retain compatibility such that existing MapReduce applications (e.g. end-user applications and projects such as ... **Apache Hive**, et al), ... work unmodified and without recompilation when used with any Apache Hadoop cluster within **the same major release** as the original build target."*

However, using version 3.1 would provide extra safety.

Comment: Can you tell which mysql connector jar to be used? Or can you help me with any appropriate download link this will be helpful.

Comment: Which jdbc driver to use depends on the rdbms type/version/platform used as a backend for Hive metastore. In case of MySQL I'd suggest you take the latest from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (and pick platform independent version).